# Eclipse says Cannot perform operation because the connection pool is closed

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I'm storing some values in SQLite Database and trying to send it to MySQL on button click. Here are the relevant codes

**MainActivity.java**

```
private class SendCollections extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < dbHandler.getCollectionCount(); i++){
                Bundle data = dbHandler.getCollectionDetails();

                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jObject.put("cust_id", data.getString("cust_id"));
                    jObject.put("col_id", colId);
                    jObject.put("method", data.getString("method"));
                    jObject.put("amount", data.getInt("amount"));
                    jObject.put("check_no", data.getInt("cheq_no"));

                    json.put(jObject);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                       
            }
            Log.d("Created JSON Array", json.toString());
            //sendJson("http://192.168.100.172/android/json_payments.php", json);
            UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
            userFunctions.syncCollections(json.toString());

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }



}
```

I'm executing the AsyncTask on button click.

**UserFunctions.java**

```
public JSONObject syncCollections(String jsonArray){

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("collections", jsonArray));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(sync_collections, params);

        Log.d("Sending JSON Array", jsonArray);

        return json;
    }
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public Bundle getCollectionDetails(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Bundle cursorData = new Bundle();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_COLLECTION;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            cursorData.putString("cust_id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID)));
            if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHEQ_NO)) == 0){
                cursorData.putString("method", "Cash");
            }else{
                cursorData.putString("method", "Cheque");
            }
            cursorData.putInt("amount", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT)));
            cursorData.putInt("cheq_no", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHEQ_NO)));
        }

        return cursorData;
    }

public int getCollectionCount(){
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_COLLECTION;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        return rowCount;
    }
```

When there's only one entry in "collection" table, their seems to be no errors (as in the logcat shows the "Sending JSON Array : "). But when there's more entries, the logcat gives the following error

**Logcat**

```
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394): Process: collector.lbfinance, PID: 11394
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:962)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:599)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at collector.lbfinance.library.DatabaseHandler.getCollectionCount(DatabaseHandler.java:355)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at collector.lbfinance.AgentHome$SendCollections.doInBackground(AgentHome.java:273)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at collector.lbfinance.AgentHome$SendCollections.doInBackground(AgentHome.java:1)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-25 10:12:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11394):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: In the DatabaseHandler.java  you are using only cursor.moveToFirst. It will only take to the first row of your table. Why are you not iterating it through all the rows using while(cursor.moveToNext) ??

Comment: Oh, yeah. A simple do{<the above code block>} while (cursor.moveToNext()) would do right?

Comment: I am not getting your question. Can you give a rough estimate of what you are trying to achieve. Like how many rows are there in your database and if you click a button should a particular row be selected or all of the rows be selected??

Comment: I'm storing receiving payment details. It can be 1 or more. The user syncs with the database when he connects to a network by clicking the sync button. I need to send the details to a php file. I want all rows of all columns of the table

Comment: i have provided the answer to you. see if this works and do accept the answer if it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the method GetCollectionDetails as below.

```
public Bundle getCollectionDetails(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Bundle cursorData = new Bundle();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_COLLECTION;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        int no_of_rows=cursor.getCount();           //count the no of rows in the database
        String[] cust_id=new String[row_count]; 
        String[] method=new String[row_count] ;
        int[] amount=new int[row_count]    
        int[] cheq_no=new int[row_count]
        int i=0;

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            cust_id[i]= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID));
            if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHEQ_NO)) == 0){
                method[i]="Cash";
            }else{
                mehod[i]="Cheque";
            }
            amount[i]= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT));
            cheq_no[i]= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHEQ_NO));
             i++;
        }
        cursorData.putStringArray("cust_id",cust_id);
         cursorData.putStringArray("method",method);
        cursorData.putIntArray("amount",amount);
         cursorData.putIntArray("cheq_no",cheq_no);
        return cursorData;
    }
```

Then in `MainActivity.java` you should write the following code.

```
int no_of_rows=dbHandler.getCollectionCount();
String[] cust_id=new String[row_count]; String[] method=new String[row_count] ; int[] amount=new int[row_count]
int[] cheq_no=new int[row_count] int i=0; Bundle data = dbHandler.getCollectionDetails(); cust_id=data.getStringArray("cust_id"); //simililarily retrive for others

for(int i = 0; i < dbHandler.getCollectionCount(); i++){ Bundle data = dbHandler.getCollectionDetails();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jObject.put("cust_id", cust_id[i]);
        json.put(jObject);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                       
}
```

I hope this should work fine for you..

Comment: Eclipse shows syntax errors in .putString. 
cust_id[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID)) should be the correct way right? And, shouldn't those be inside a do while?

Comment: see if it working now. And by the way I have not tested the code on my eclipse. I am just trying to provide you the logic. There may be some compile errors. Let me know if you face any more difficulty.

Comment: Thanks. I can see why my method was stupid and wrong and this should work. But I'm still getting the previous error. Even with the initial code, at least it should output the duplicates right? But I'm (still, even after changing it to this) getting the same set of errors as shown in the OP

Comment: It seems like the problem was me trying to access the database from the background thread. It works fine now. Thanks for the help mate, you are awesome